# Ajax CORS Headers Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm really struggling to figure out why this CORS request is getting denied. It's been driving me crazy. It gives an error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://api.example.com/v1/users/me" and then a message about cross-domain/CORS in Firebug.

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var settings = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Token token= 12345'
            },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        };

        var deferred = jQuery.ajax('http://api.example.com/v1/users/me', settings).then(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);            
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );

});
```

**Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /v1/users/me HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 04:28:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dfa4a0638bcf104d316f7358153bb2f9; path=/
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: application/json
X-Cache: MISS from 172.19.134.2
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from 172.19.134.2:3128
Via: 1.0 172.19.134.2:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE14)
Connection: close
```

If anyone is interested, I have this in PHP:

**PHP**

```
// Set Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization');      
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the CORS is failing simply because of the HTTP 500 code returned from the server. Thus, although the response contains valid information for CORS, the client ignores the information due to the message code indicating the response being invalid.

Why 500 is being returned, is dependent on your server configs/app.

Comment: OK interesting. I have it just doing an echo and die, so maybe that is why.

Comment: The endpoint used in the tester: http://api.getlivin.co/v1/users/me, is returning both an HTTP 200 as well as  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` Am not sure how to correlate this with what you are observing in your case. Since your original problem had the endpoint api.example.com (which I could not resolve), i assume this was a local setup. If the endpoint publicly accessible, maybe I can try it directly.

Comment: Correct! I had set a header() response code twice. Good tip!